# Holt's Linear and Holt-Winters in R

Tags: r, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

With the below code, I have run Holt's linear and Holt-Winters forecasts using Excel / Solver. I wanted to replicate this using R (Excel can be a pain) but I am getting the below error with `hw()`.

It is my first time running this with R so I am trying to go by the docs. I assume running the function will pick the initialization and also optimize the parameters? Or am I way off?

Either way, I thought `hw()` would work, but clearly I am doing something wrong here.

```
   x<-c(12638.8,11583.3,13024.1,12594.2,13068.1,12765.4,13125.6,13316.3,13054.7,13879.3,14436.6,17861,13923.8,12418.4,13854.4,13558.8,14335,13639.9,14132.2,14457.2,14045.4,14941.2,15556,18984.2,14825.5,13138.3,14473.6,14507.6,15055.9,14384.2,15199.7,15169.7,15223.5,16412.9,16662.9,20638.9,16154.8,14696,15793.8,15804.2,15895,15868.6,16435.6,15945.9,16381.4,17084.2,17261,21652.6,16330.6,14840.5,16419.8,16104.2,16326.2,16453.4,16750.3,16678,16816.4,17431.7,17920.6,22491.3,17016.6,15534.8,17339.2,17065.6,17313.3,17448.2,17617.5,17814.2,17747.6,18592.4,19223.3,23636.1)
    x.ts <- ts(x, start=2001, frequency=12)

plot(x.ts)

####Holt's Linear
holt(x, h=12, damped=FALSE, level=c(80,95), fan=FALSE, 
    initial=c("optimal"), exponential=FALSE,
    alpha=NULL, beta=NULL)

#Holt-Winters
hw(x, h=2*frequency(x), seasonal="multiplicative", damped=FALSE, 
    level=c(80,95), fan=FALSE, initial=c("optimal"), 
    exponential=TRUE, alpha=NULL, beta=NULL, gamma=NULL)

# hw gives the following error
#Error in ets(x, "AAA", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, damped = damped,  : Nonseasonal data
```

Comment: Some confusion here. Holt was the supervisor and Winters was his student and co-author. Their methods are thus often known as Holt-Winters. Nothing to do with the season "winter".

Comment: Corrected title. Cheers for the spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you the problem. You have passed non-seasonal data to `hw()`. Note that you have passed `x` rather than `x.ts` to both functions.

Comment: Wow that was a comical error. (late night coding) Thanks for the response. Looking at the `HoltWinters()` function this morning, is this the preferred method? If my dataset is a seasonal Multiplicative data set, is this the only thing that needs to be coded using R that will estimate and optimise the parameters, `(m <- HoltWinters(AirPassengers, seasonal = "mult"))`

Comment: You are better off using `ets()` from the `forecast` package. It includes Holt-Winters as a special case, but provides a much richer class of models and selects the best one for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using `ets()` I would specify `ets(x.ts, model="MAN"` with the `opt.crit=c("mse")` for Holt's Linear and for Holt-Winters' `model="MAM"` 
I want to be able to demonstrate the differences between these 2 models rather than let the algorithm decide which model best suits.

Comment: Use model="ZAN" for Holt and "ZAM" for Holt-Winters additive. The Z allows ets() to decide if you it is better to use an additive or multiplicative error. And use damped=FALSE if you don't want damping.

Comment: Great! tks. Does the algorithm iterate through the parameters? I left `alpha=NULL, beta=NULL` and I used `opt.crit=c("mse")`  However, the number produced for the ZAN model is 2490139. I tested for arbitrary parameter of 0.5 for both alpha and beta and the number is even bigger. Is the 2490139 an acceptable value for MSE? seems rather large.. Or is this because the data set I am using is multiplicative (tested using model="ZZZ") & using a model that does not factor seasonal will produce this large number? Where as `model="ZAM"` does a much better job because it factors seasonal with HW model.